# iis 7 app pool user privilege

Tags: iis-7

On iis7 on windows server 2008, we are creating a customized user for the app pool for our asp.net website. what user right /user group should I set for this user?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS7 you only need to grant them access to the website path on disk, unless they need specific permissions to the registry or other object, in which case it depends on your usage.  Most of the time it's just NTFS on disk though.